# Count Assets Barcodes and Group by Rooms

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, count

I have 2 tables `Asset Register` and `LocationRoom`. I want to count the number of asset barcodes in each room.

I want the output to be the list of Asset Barcodes, Description,RoomNo and count for assets by room.

for example Room R0001 has 4 assets (01780,01781,01782,01783).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c2cb3/2

Comment: So do you want comma separated lists of the assets, Descriptions based on the LocationRoomID / RoomNo?

Comment: @RandiVertongen yes please i want to see all my 19 asset barcodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This does Query uses XML string concatenation to get the result in the format you need.**

*If `AssetID` or `Description` can be NULL then you would have to add additional logic*

```
SELECT  '('+reverse(stuff(reverse(( 
        SELECT A.[AssetID] +',' 
        FROM [dbo].[AssetRegister] A
        WHERE A.LocationRoomID = AR.LocationRoomID
        FOR XML PATH(''))), 1, 2,''))+')'
        , 
        '('+reverse(stuff(reverse(( 
        SELECT A.[Description] +',' 
        FROM [dbo].[AssetRegister] A
        WHERE A.LocationRoomID = AR.LocationRoomID
        FOR XML PATH(''))), 1, 2,''))+')'
      ,LR.[RoomNo]
      ,COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[AssetRegister] AR
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LocationRoom] LR
on AR.LocationRoomID = LR.LocationRoomID
GROUP BY LR.[RoomNo],AR.LocationRoomID;
```

Result
[image]

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=650d7f135d60f20b05d6fbebe3de36b9)

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c2cb3/5)

**Edit:**

> Thank you very much is it possible to get all the 19 rows each one
>   with their AssetBarcode 01780, Dell Computer, R001, 4

```
SELECT  AR.AssetID, 
        AR.[Description],
        LR.[RoomNo],
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY LR.RoomNo)
FROM [dbo].[AssetRegister] AR
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LocationRoom] LR
on AR.LocationRoomID = LR.LocationRoomID
```

**Result**

```
AssetID Description RoomNo  (No column name)
01780   DELL LAPTOP R0001   4
01781   DELL MONITOR    R0001   4
01782   DELL CPU    R0001   4
01783   DELL KEYBOARD   R0001   4
01784   HP LAPTOP   R0002   4
01785   HP MONITR   R0002   4
01786   HP CPU  R0002   4
01787   HP KEYBOARD R0002   4
01788   APPLE LAPTOP AIR    R0003   8
...*(19 rows)*
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9fccd8f481a15967aa83b423efc07b41)

Comment: Thank you very much is it possible to get all the 19 rows each one with their AssetBarcode 01780, Dell Computer, R001, 4

Comment: @SenyoAborgah Edited it, like that?

Comment: that's 100% the output I wanted. So you used COUNT(*) OVER PARTITION BY RoomNo. Thank You very much